# How can I customize my chapter and section titles like in the following picture?

Tags: chapters, section-titles

I'm writing my thesis and came though this beautiful chapter style. How can I replicate it? With the color blue and the same fonts for the chapter and section titles. The first letter of the text should also be capitalized with the color blue.

[image]